# How to Save Front-end Feedback Form Data in database table Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.2.5, magento2.2.6

I want to save form data in a table, I searched a lot of stuff but unable to do it

here i created a form in form.phtml file

```
<form >
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">

    <label for="lname">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email-Id">

    <label for="mobile">Mobile No.</label>
    <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number">

    <label for="feedback">Feedback</label>
    <textarea id="feedback" name="feedback" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

please tell me what changes in phtml file and how I save this form data in a table

I am able to create a table with the proper field but unable to save data in the table

Comment: Have you created `Controller` and `model` ?

Comment: till now I didn't create Controller and model, but I want to do this with using Controller

Comment: as a start, you can try https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html and http://bilalusean.com/create-read-update-delete-crud-magento-2/